# How to get the selected value of select option using java code

Tags: java, jsp

I'm studying Java Web. And now, I have a question like that. This is my code in JSP file:

```
<select id="ddlFruits" name="ddlFruits" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue()">
   <option value="0">Banana</option>
   <option value="1">Apple</option>
   <option value="2">Mango</option>
   <option value="3">Orange</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedTextValue() {
        var t = document.getElementById("ddlFruits");
                var fruitsID = t.options[t.selectedIndex].value;
        <%
             // How to get Value of fruitsID in here???

             // do something with fruitsID.
         %>
}
</script>
```

How to get the selected value of select option (variable : fruitsID ) in <%  // Java Code %>.
I used this code: request.getParameter("fruitsID ").
But it returned null.
Thanks for advance!

Comment: You'll need to submit the form to get the value the client has selected.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121295/how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-drop-down-list-in-jsp

Comment: In my jsp file has two select option, and the second select option will get value base on the selected value of the first select option. So, I haven't submited the form yet.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not technically possible. The Java code will be executed before the HTML is even rendered, so there's no way to get the current selection in Java, unless you submit the form and then capture the value.

Comment: You can not get the value in Java but in JS or Jquery you can.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221957/jquery-to-retrieve-and-set-selected-option-value-of-html-select-element

Comment: Server side: Java. Client side: JavaScript. You're misunderstanding where and when each executes.