# Assigning selected value of a dropdown to a variable within a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, dropdown

I have a dropdown which contain language names while value contains the code of each language.

```
<select name="country">

            <% 

          Map<String,String> langCode = x.getCountryList();
           for( Object key :langCode.keySet() )
           {%>
           <option value="<%=(String)key%>"><%=langCode.get(key) %> </option>
              <% 
           }

          %>
         </select>
```

Now I want to get the value of the selected language from the dropdown and assign it to a variable within the JSP page as I have to pass that value to a servlet page.Thank you

Comment: Maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121295/how-to-get-the-selected-value-from-drop-down-list-in-jsp

Comment: I tried this.But it returns a null value

Comment: Have you included your select inside a form and you can not get the parameter "country" from the request?

Comment: Yes. I have a form in which the dropdown is declared

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing selected dropdown items using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445715/accessing-selected-dropdown-items-using-java)