# Accessing selected dropdown items using Java

Tags: java, jsp, html-select

I have a dropdown which consist the language names. I am setting the value and displaying name of the dropdown by using a hashmap.

```
 <form action="TextTranslation" method="post" class="form" role="form" >
        <div class="row">
            <div  id = "imageView" class="col-lg-8 center-block ">

         <div class="btn-group"> 
         <select name="country">

            <% 

          Map<String,String> langCode = x.getCountryList();
           for( Object key :langCode.keySet() )
           {%>


           <option value="<%=(String)key%>"><%=langCode.get(key) %> </option>
              <% 

              System.out.println((String)key);
           }

           String name =  request.getParameter("country");
           request.setAttribute("code", name);

            %>



        </select>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" class= "btn btn-image" value="Translate">

                <a href="#search" class="btn btn-default bg-light-gray">Search Text</a>

            </div>
        </div>
          </form>
```

Values are passed correctly to dropbox as it print all the values in console. the set attribute is accessed in the particular servlet. But it gives a null value. Do you have any idea?Thank you in advance

**UPDATED**

```
<select name="country"> 
    <% 
       Map<String,String> langCode = x.getCountryList(); 
        for( Object key :langCode.keySet() ) 
          {%>
               <option value="<%=(String)key%>"><%=langCode.get(key) %> /option> 
               <% System.out.println((String)key); 
           } 
         String name = request.getParameter("country"); 
    %> 
</select> 

<input type="hidden" name="code" value = <%= name%>/> .
```

In the servlet I used,

```
 request.getParameter("code");
```

Comment: while you are going to submit this form at Servlet(TextTranslation) then at servlet side you are getting your set value(aka, "code"-> name) getting as a null right ?

Comment: I use request.getParameter("code"); and when I print this value i get a null value

Answer (score 0):

update your jsp likewise,

```
<form...>
...
<input type="hidden" name="code" value = <%= name%>/> 
....
</form>
```

then get it from your servlet likewise,

```
 request.getParameter("code"); // will return value of code
```

**NOTE :**

Remove from your `jsp-code` if above solution you gonna implement then,

```
 request.setAttribute("code", name);
```

Comment: It still gives the null value

Comment: @TharinduRanasinghe you are submitting form to servlet right ?

Comment: Yes. This is the updated code <select name="country">
      <% 
           Map<String,String> langCode = x.getCountryList();
           for( Object key :langCode.keySet() )
           {%>
            <option value="<%=(String)key%>"><%=langCode.get(key) %> </option>
            <% 
             System.out.println((String)key);
           }
           String name =  request.getParameter("country");
            %>
         </select>
           <input type="hidden" name="code" value = <%= name%>/> .In the servlet I used request.getParameter("code");

Comment: @TharinduRanasinghe see i update you "updated code" into your question, inside it i can see option-tag is not closed properly. can you do it. and let me know further if still not resolved then.

Comment: @TharinduRanasinghe wrap double-quote around value's of hidden input tag.

Comment: check your request.getParameter("country")-> value if it's null then obviously you will get null, also check scope of name-variable. you can also replace name into hidden field by request.getParameter("country") directly.